# What happened to Yamato?

Tags: naruto

Is yamato dead? If not what happened to him. We saw him being taken prisoner by Kabuto and then we never see or hear from him again, even with Kabuto defeated we see no mention of him. So what happened to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yamato was controlled by spiral zetsu (tobi) just before the infinite tsukuyomi. Since Yamato and zetsu both know wood release, their powers combined was enough to stop the Third Hokage with "Sage Art Wood Release: True Several Thousand Hands".

Chapter 677
[image: Chapter 677]
Episode 426
[image: Episode 426]